# Handling empty request body (protobuf3 encoded)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, protocol-buffers

I have a Spring Boot application running. Requests/responses are sent protobuf (Protobuf3) encoded.

My (simplified) REST controller:

```
@RestController
public class ServiceController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/foo/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void doStuff(@PathVariable int userId, @RequestBody(required = false) Stuff.Request pbRequest) {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

My (simplified) protobuf3 schema:

```
syntax = "proto3";

message Request {
    int32 data = 1;
}
```

My configuration to have content negotiation available:

```
@Configuration
public class ProtobufConfig {
    @Bean
    ProtobufHttpMessageConverter protobufHttpMessageConverter() {
        return new ProtobufHttpMessageConverter();
    }
}
```

Everything is working like a charm as long as the request body has some bytes set. BUT protobuf does not write any bytes if just default values are sent. As soon I have a request message which contains `data = 0` the generated bytes are just empty. On the app side the request body is `null` and won't be converted to a protobuf message (it even throws an exception if request body is set to `required = true`). The HTTP input message isn't processed by the `ProtobufHttpMessageConverter` at all. Is there a way to handle that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way of handling it. But it uses reflection which is really something I don't want to have:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RequestBodyAdviceChain implements RequestBodyAdvice {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter methodParameter, Type type,
            Class< ? extends HttpMessageConverter< ? >> aClass) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object handleEmptyBody(Object body, HttpInputMessage httpInputMessage, MethodParameter methodParameter,
            Type type, Class< ? extends HttpMessageConverter< ? >> aClass) {
        try {
            Class<?> cls = Class.forName(type.getTypeName());
            Method m = cls.getMethod("getDefaultInstance");
            return m.invoke(null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return body;
    }

    @Override
    public HttpInputMessage beforeBodyRead(HttpInputMessage httpInputMessage, MethodParameter methodParameter,
            Type type, Class< ? extends HttpMessageConverter< ? >> aClass) throws IOException {
        return httpInputMessage;
    }

    @Override
    public Object afterBodyRead(Object body, HttpInputMessage httpInputMessage, MethodParameter methodParameter, Type type,
            Class< ? extends HttpMessageConverter< ? >> aClass) {
        return body;
    }
}
```

So in the case of an empty body I create a default instance of the protobuf message object.